# iOS - EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error

Tags: objective-c, ios, error-handling, exc-bad-access

I am developing an iPhone/ iPod app. The following code is the .m file of a UIViewController. I get the following:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2......
```

when I hit the following line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I understand that this typically happens when you try to access an object after you released it, but I do not release it before I try to access it. I have attached the complete code below.

Any help is thankful!

```
#import "HomePage.h"
#import "HusbandryRecordsMain.h"
#import "TaskManagerMain.h"
#import "AnimalInventoryMain.h"
#import "FeedInventoryMain.h"

@implementation HomePage
@synthesize options, datasource;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self setupArray];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)setupArray{
    options = [NSMutableArray  arrayWithObjects:@"Husbandry Records", @"Task Manager", @"Feeder Inventory", @"Animal Inventory", nil];

    datasource = options;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    // THE FOLLOWING LINE IS THROWING THE ERROR!
    cell.textLabel.text = [datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

    //Arrow 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        HusbandryRecordsMain *hrm = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Husbandry Records - Main"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:hrm animated:YES];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        TaskManagerMain *tmm = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Task Manager - Main"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tmm animated:YES];
    } 
    else if (indexPath.row == 2){
        FeedInventoryMain *fim = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Feeder Inventory - Main"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:fim animated:YES];
    }  
    else if (indexPath.row == 3){
        AnimalInventoryMain *aim = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Animal Inventory - Main"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:aim animated:YES];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

//----------------------TABLEVIEWCELL HEIGHT -------------------------------------------

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 70;

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Comment: Use ARC unless you have a very compelling reason not to.

Comment: if you are just learning to fly, don't use arc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of your files options and datasource? Also try self.options etc.

Comment: datasource is a NSArray and options is NSMutableArray

Comment: well. why do you need two arrays to keep your data? you probably have retained them (strong or retain). use self.option only and don't forget to release it in dealloc method.

Comment: return 4; can be return [self.option count];

Comment: THANK YOU!! and what does the dealloc method look like? I dont have one, i know bad memory management :/ i just havent worked with obj-c alot

Comment: somewhere in your .m file place the method; -(void)dealloc { [option release];[super dealloc];} So, it means your responsibility is to release the retained objects in this method. otherwise you'll produce memory leaks.

Comment: The type of options and datasource has nothing to do with the crash;  the crash is quite straightforward.   The suggestion to "try something" to fix the problem without indication as to why that will work/fix the problem is s surefire way to dig the hole deeper....

Answer (score 5):

```
-(void)setupArray{
    options = [NSMutableArray  arrayWithObjects:@"Husbandry Records", @"Task Manager", @"Feeder Inventory", @"Animal Inventory", nil];

    datasource = options;
}
```

You are assigning an autoreleased object to the `datasource` instance variable directly and then attempting to use it after it is released in the line of code that is crashing.  If you turned on Zombie detection, it would have very likely have caught this directly.   As well, the static analyzer (build and analyze) should have caught it.

(Unless, of course, you have ARC enabled at which point something else is going on...)

Comment: What is Zombie detection? I am unfamiliar with this. ARC is turned off - should i keep it on? And, ok, well how would I fix this?

Comment: You need to `retain` options;  either by using `self.datasource = options;` or `datasource = [options retain];`.  You should be using ARC overall, if this is new code.   However, you really should go and learn the basics of Objective-C and memory management or this is going to be the first of many issues/crashers that will cause headaches (walk before you run and all that).